# Action after a form submit and return to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Now I want to make some change of my web after user submit a form.

Since the form submitted and will connect database to update, after it, the web page may have some change like the visible will change.

I have tried put the action after submit, like following code:

```
 function <portlet:namespace />uploadExcel() {
        if ($('#uploadedFile').val().trim().length == 0) {
            alert("Please choose a file!");
            return false;
        }else{
        document.UploadExcelForm.submit();
        $("#FileFrame").attr("style","width:1000;height:600;");
        console.log("uploaded");
    }
        }
```

But after submit, the page will like refresh, and the visible of the frame will become cant see again.

Also, if I use ajax for uploading, how can I call the portletfunction after upload?

```
<portlet:actionURL var="checkworkbook" name="checkWorkbook"></portlet:actionURL>
<b>Please Upload a Document</b> 

 <form id = "UploadExcelForm" name ="UploadExcelForm" action="<%=checkworkbook%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="uploadedFile" name="uploadedFile" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel">
<button type="button" onclick="<portlet:namespace />uploadExcel()"> Upload </button>
</form>
```

Comment: The form submit always refresh the page. If you want to send a form without refreshing the page, you should use ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You should use preventDefault()

Comment: @Roy I have do some searching for ajax upload, but it seems still need to use form method to upload the file

Comment: @summerhkg Yeap, I use dropzone.js (https://www.dropzonejs.com/) to upload files and ajax to submit data.